# CSS div tag inherit dimensions from table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am not such an expert in CSS;

My question is: can a `div` tag inherit dimensions from a `table` rows based on table row's `class` or `id`?

For example: We have a table with a couple of rows, but we don't know exact size of one table row, but we know the id/class of the rows. And by absolute positioning a div tag on table based on id/class to fill up 2 rows from start to end!

Can anyone point me to some addresses or to give me a tip code?

```
<table>
    <col width="9%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I search for something like this:

[image: div and the table]

Comment: You should post some sample code and/or explain what you have tried

Comment: I tried with HTML Grids, HTML Tables, CSS, jQuery but no code yet

Comment: With what dimensions? :)

Comment: Are you willing to wrap these rows in a different tbody?

Comment: One moment i will edit the question with the table HTML code

Comment: Done! In my question is now my HTML Table code

Comment: I think jQuery Resizable widget (Snap to Grid) will do the job!

Comment: Did anyone on this comment thread downvote the question because of a lack of an example? If so, please remove your downvote, as the OP has provided an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the width and height of parent td and then set them to the div using javascript.You want something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/toLacq32/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
tdWidth = $('#inner-div').closest('td').width();
tdHeight = $('#inner-div').closest('td').height();
$("#inner-div").width( tdWidth ).height(tdHeight);
});
```